# I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{Z}_2\cong \mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: group-theory

How do I prove that$$\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{Z}_2\cong \mathbb{R}^*$$
I do some work but I stuck.

Comment: In what sense? I'm confused by the tags - I think you mean as an isomorphism of groups? In this case, consider the map $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \{1, -1\}$ and try thinking about sending a pair $(r, a)$ to $r$ times a sign depending on $a$.

Comment: @T.Bongers - Yes, Imeant isomorphism of groups. This what I have ( what you telling me about, but how does it helps me? I do I prove with it the isomorphism..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi((r,\sigma)) = (2\sigma-1)r$.

Then $\phi^{-1}(x) = (|x|, \frac{1}{2}(1+\operatorname{sgn} x))$.

Note that $\phi((r_1, \sigma_1) * (r_2, \sigma_2)) = \phi((r_1 r_2, \sigma_1 \sigma_2)) = (2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2-1) r_1 r_2$. Since $\sigma_k \in \{0,1\}$, we have $(2 \sigma_1 \sigma_2-1) = (2 \sigma_1-1) (2 \sigma_2 -1)$, so this gives
$\phi((r_1, \sigma_1) * (r_2, \sigma_2)) =(2 \sigma_1-1)r_1(2 \sigma_2-1)r_2 = \phi((r_1,\sigma_1))* \phi((r_2,\sigma_2) $. Hence $\phi$ is a homomorphism. The above shows that $\phi$ is a bijection, hence an isomorphism.

Comment: What is $r$,$\sigma$ means?

Comment: $(r,\sigma) \in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: And this $\phi$ prove the iso.?

Comment: Well, you need to show that it is a homomorphism, but this is almost immediate.

Comment: This what I don't understand, how I prove with this that this is iso.??
Thank you!

Comment: Show $\phi((r_1,\sigma_1)) * \phi((r_2,\sigma_2)) = \phi( (r_1,\sigma_1) * (r_2,\sigma_2) ) $.

Comment: @YoavFridman There are three things to check to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism: It needs to be a homomorphism (which is what copper.hat's comment is about), it needs to be injective, and it needs to be surjective.

Comment: Can you help me prove it please? Thank you!

Comment: Well, show it is a homomorphism first, using what I wrote two comments above. Note that $*$ is different in the two groups. Then the above answer shows that it is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have an exact sequence $$0 \to \mathbb{R}^+ \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^* \overset{\mathrm{sign}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0.$$

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you explain little more?
Thank you!

Comment: I mean that $\mathrm{sign} : x \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} -1 & \text{if} \ x <0 \\ 1 & \text{if} \ x>0 \end{array} \right.$ defines a homomorphism $\mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_2 = \{ \pm 1\}$ whose kernel is $\mathbb{R}^+$.